# Convert NA values in a specific column to "" field in R

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a dataset, df that I reading in from Excel to R. For some reason, when reading in the file, R sets all the empty fields to NA. How do I reverse this? I want the NA values in the column to be converted back to empty cells.

```
                      Subject     Value
                      hello       NA
                      hello       NA
                      hello       NA
```

I would like:

```
                      Subject     Value
                      hello       
                      hello       
                      hello
```

Here is the dput:

```
  structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "hello", class = "factor"), 
  Value = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
  df[is.na(df$Value)]   <- " "
```

.

I do not know if this structure is correct
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to assign the same column name

```
df$Value[is.na(df$Value)] <- ""
```

Instead, if we do the subset on the whole dataset, it would result in error

```
df1[is.na(df1$Value)]
```

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df1, is.na(df1$Value)) :    undefined columns
>   selected

---

With `tidyverse`, we can also use `replace_na`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
          mutate(Value = replace_na(Value, ""))
df1
#    Subject Value
#1   hello      
#2   hello      
#3   hello
```

Comment: The first worked fine. I will upvote in 12 minutes. Thank you